# Cocos2d scroll layer on Sprite drag

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, camera

I have designed a small tutorial named "Stacker", As the name suggests, The game involves stacking blocks on each other. I have a large number of blocks to be stacked and hence all cant be accomodated in the screen itself... I m new to cocos2d and box2d but have managed to create a body with its adjoining sprite wen a user clicks on the screen. I have used MouseJoint to give movement to the body till the user performs the drag action that is till the user takes his finger off the screen.

The problem is that i need to follow the sprite (actually need the camera to follow the sprite) when the user drags it above the screen space, i referred the following links with no success... i guess wat i need is to move the body to a virtual coordinates which m not getting coz even if the screen does shift using the camera methods, but the sprite doesnt move with respect to the screen...

[cocos2d forum link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5363)

[flash concept but box2d](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/05/04/following-a-body-with-the-camera-in-box2d-the-smart-way/)

Can some1 guide me in case i need to have some pre-requisites before following camera in the manner i specified.. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys!

Got it guys! Had to take a global variable which records the increments per frame, The increments were equal to the layer movement which i did by setting the position of the layer to a unit less in every frame! Then set the Mouse join to the target which is (ScreenCoordinates + increment) dis too has to be done in every frame!

Done!

Cool method but needed a bit of brainstorming!!